# Algorithm regarding relations

Tags: algorithms

A is a finite set and let ~ be a relation on A, given the following algorithm:

- Let $R$=~
- As long as there are $p,q,r \in A$ such that $pRq$ and $qRr$ but not $pRr$, add $(p,r)$ to $R$
- Output $R$

Prove that the algorithm finishes in a finite amount of steps and give an upper bound on the number of steps. Call the constructed set $R$=~$_T$. Prove ~$_T$ is transitive. Prove that ~$_T$ is the smallest transitive relation containing ~, i.e: ~$\leq$~$_T$. And that for any transitive relation ~' such that ~$\leq$~' we have ~$_T$$\leq$~'

Now my idea is to partition the set A into the two subsets, say B and C where B is the set of all elements in A that are not transitive with respect to R and C then are the remaining elements in A. And since A is finite, any subset such as B must also be finite and the algorithm finishes in finite steps. The set B here is then equal to the set $R$ after the algorithm and so is an upper bound the size of set B? I'm not really sure how to prove the rest.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand it properly, but you're saying, that the algorithm takes all elements in $A$ such that these elements are not transitive (otherwise it would say $pRr$)  and this set then is transitive?

Comment: Yes, that is confusing me.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set , I did'nt know about the notion of transitive sets in that way.

Comment: Okay, do you think my method of showing it's finite is sufficient?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure

Comment: @lhf How do I apply that in this case?

Comment: @Leonchino, lhf can I interpret it as the set ~$_T$ is transitive since an element of every pair (p,q) in ~$_T$ is an element of ~$_T$?